# Relationships between finiteness of stable rank and IBN property of rings

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-rings

Does any ring of finite stable rank have IBN property? Where can we find this result?

Comment: You probably mean to ask if *every* ring of finite stable rank has the IBN property. The way the question is written it can be interpreted two ways. Also, the question becomes better if you define some of the terms.

Comment: Veldkamp claims this (Handbook of incidence geometry, prop. 2.6 pag. 1040). I suppose that his references give a proof.

Comment: Crossposted to math.SE a few days later: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702848/relation-between-finite-stable-rank-and-ibn-invariant-basis-number  Talking with the OP, I found out he was interested in rings with stable range $n$ (apparently synonymous with stable rank $n$) for $n>1$. Rings with stable range 1 do indeed have IBN.